# Difficulty in moving the LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `linearlayout` which contains some other layouts, and I need to able to move this layout by holding it. I have implemented this code and its moving. But the problem is it vibrates more when I touch it (vibrates even on moving the layout).

Here is my code that I tried...

```
private int _xDelta;
private int _yDelta;
LinearLayout ll= (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.layoutid);
ll.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent ev) {
                final int x_cord = (int) ev.getX();
                final int y_cord = (int) ev.getY();
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
                final int action = ev.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    _xDelta = x_cord - (int) ll.getX();
                    _yDelta = y_cord - (int) ll.getY();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                        ll.setX(x_cord - _xDelta);
                        ll.setY(y_cord - _yDelta);
                    } else {

                    }

                    break;
                }

                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: try without inner layouts, does it still vibrate?

Comment: I need inner layouts and views. Those holds data. And I have an image as a background also. All these are necessary for the project.

Comment: I know, but i mean if you delete everything for now and try without the inner layout, then it would be easier to see where is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may be what X and Y values you are getting. The `getX()` and `getY()` methods get an interpolated point, whereas `getRawX()` and `getRawY()` will get you the more exact points you want, which should fix the *vibrating* issue.